# HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error Django on iis Error Code 0x00000067

Tags: django, windows, iis, fastcgi

I'm trying to make`django` web app work on IIS using `wfastcgi`

Following [This guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cgTFrAwXeoI) it gave me the error code 0x00000067

[image]

and here is my web.config file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="AccuManager" path="*" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="E:\projectInnoventiq\accuManager\venv\Scripts\python.exe|E:\projectInnoventiq\accuManager\venv\Scripts\wfastcgi.py" resourceType="Unspecified" />
        </handlers>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
        <tracing>
            <traceFailedRequests>
                <add path="*">
                    <traceAreas>
                        <add provider="ASP" verbosity="Verbose" />
                        <add provider="ASPNET" areas="Infrastructure,Module,Page,AppServices" verbosity="Verbose" />
                        <add provider="ISAPI Extension" verbosity="Verbose" />
                        <add provider="WWW Server" areas="Authentication,Security,Filter,StaticFile,CGI,Compression,Cache,RequestNotifications,Module,FastCGI,WebSocket" verbosity="Verbose" />
                    </traceAreas>
                    <failureDefinitions timeTaken="00:00:00" statusCodes="500" />
                </add>
            </traceFailedRequests>
        </tracing>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: wfastcgi is deprecated by Microsoft. You should use Python on Linux if possible.

Comment: @LexLi my client works on windows, sadly I need to find any way to deploy the Django app on windows, no other alt for IIS?

Comment: try to assign iusr and iis_user full permission for the python folder and site folder.

Comment: @JalpaPanchal after giving the permission error code changed to `0xc0000135`

Comment: configure the handler as:<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <clear/>
      <add name="FastCGI" path="*" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="D:\python\python.exe|d:\sites\esplayer\esplayer\manage.py fcgi --pythonpath=d:\sites\esplayer --settings=esplayer.settings" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration> .point python.exe file to python installed folder.

Comment: Did you find any solution?